# How does one atomically use a set of handles?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stdin, handle, atomic

Let's say you have a program with a bunch of threads. The one thread would like to freeze access to stdin, stdout, and stderr (causing any other threads or keyboards to block until its done) so that its output doesn't get interweaved with them. Is there a way to do this directly, or would there have to be a manager thread, you know, managin' the handle. Relatedly, could you cause any input on stdin to block any output on stdout until it received and handled (atomically)?

Comment: I have a vague recollection of somebody claiming that `stdout` *already* prevents interleaving of text within a single line. I cannot find an authoritative reference for that though...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid If you change `putStLn` to `putStr` in either of my examples, you will see interleaving of text within a single line.

Comment: Then apparently I was mistaken...

Answer (score 3):

You can easily simulate a lock for controlling access to a resource with an [`MVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html). You aquire the lock by taking the value with [`takeMVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#v:takeMVar) and release the lock by replacing the value with [`putMVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#v:takeMVar). For example, we can define something like the following

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
    stdinLock <- newMVar ()              -- create a new lock for stdin (unaquired)
    let    
        printWithLabel a b = do
            takeMVar stdinLock           -- aquire the lock for stdin
            putStrLn (show a ++ ":")
            print b
            putMVar stdinLock ()         -- release the lock for stdin
        actions = map fork $ zipWith printWithLabel [1..26] ['A'..]
    doneSignals <- sequence actions
    sequence doneSignals
    return ()

fork :: IO a -> IO (IO ())
fork a = do
    done <- newEmptyMVar 
    forkIO (a >> putMVar done ())
    return (takeMVar done)
```

We could extract the locking functionality into another function

```
withLock :: MVar () -> IO a -> IO a
withLock lock action = do
    takeMVar lock
    x <- action
    putMVar lock ()
    return x
```

`withLock` performs an `IO` action after acquiring a lock and releases it when were done. This doesn't properly handle what to do if the code throws exceptions and notably will not release the lock if an exception is thrown. The [`Lock`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-extra-0.7.0.9/docs/Control-Concurrent-Lock.html) in [concurrent-extra](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-extra) provides a similar helper function which [brackets](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket_) an operation (handling exceptions) with acquiring and releasing a lock.

In terms of `Lock` and [`async`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) the above example can be simplified to

```
import qualified Control.Concurrent.Lock as Lock
import Control.Concurrent.Async

main = do
    stdinLock <- Lock.new
    let    
        printWithLabel a b = Lock.with stdinLock $ do
            putStrLn (show a ++ ":")
            print b
        actions = zipWith printWithLabel [1..26] ['A'..]
    doneSignals <- mapM async actions
    mapM_ wait doneSignals
```

If you want a thread reading input on stdin to block output from other threads to stdout you can use a single lock to control both stdin and stdout.

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to have this work with existing code. Locks require everything to support them.

Comment: @PyRulez If you don't somehow mark the edges of where threads are and are not allowed to interleave there are two possibilities: threads are allowed to interleave everywhere (no locks) or threads are not allowed to interleave anywhere (serial execution). If you remove the `Lock.with stdinLock $` from the last example none of the underlying existing calls to write to `stdout` interleave with each other, but the output data is still nonsense (all the labels first followed by all of the values).